# How to bound this integral?

Tags: calculus

I want to ask how a hint how to show this integral inequality:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x}{y^{2}+x^{2}}\log\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi y}}dy< \frac{1}{12x}
$$
This is from Ahlfors, Complex Analysis, page $206$. I tried to compute a rough bound, but my bound is too rough and it did not work.

Explicit computation showed the bound is quite delicate, for example for $x=6000$ the value on the left hand side is $0.000013888888876028806686426283065381014133382406390603...$ as opposed to $0.00001388888888...$. For $x=60000$ the accuracy is about $0.99999999999074074074$, for $x=75000$ the accuracy is about $0.99999999999407407407$.

This is the refinement term in the usual Stirling's formula. I know it for a long time but I never knew how to prove it.

Comment: It might not work but did you have a go at polar coordinates?

Comment: The numeric integral value is wrong.

Comment: Up to 50 digits, it is:0.00013888888760288076050033800243611840892960169910069

Comment: How is $0.0001\ldots$ less than $0.00001\ldots$ then?

Comment: It seems I had a typo in my command. The correct result should be 0.000013888888876028806686426283065381014133382406390603...

Comment: Anyway, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @user88595: This is really a 1 variable integral. I do not think changing it into polar coordinates would simplify anything.

Comment: Dirty trick: instead of writing $\sum \frac{1}{(z+n)^2}$ as an integral of $\frac{\pi\cot \pi\zeta}{(z+\zeta)^2}$, use $\frac{1}{(z+n)^2} = \int_0^\infty te^{-(z+n)t}\,dt$. That leads to the expression $$\int_0^\infty e^{-zt}\left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{dt}{t}$$ for the refinement term, and $$0 \leqslant \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \leqslant \frac{1}{12}$$ for $t\geqslant 0$ can be verified elementarily (but a little tediously).

Comment: @DanielFischer: I see. This seems to be really helpful, since the integral is really difficult to evaluate.

Comment: It seems a bit like cheating, but looking at the other integral, I have no idea yet how to attack it directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint 1**:

$${x^2\over x^2+y^2}\lt1$$

**Hint 2**:

$${1\over w}\log{1\over1-w}=1+{1\over2}w+{1\over3}w^2+\cdots$$

(Note:  I'll flesh this out if the OP requests, but all the questions asked for was a hint.)

Comment: D'oh, didn't think simple enough (+1). Out of curiosity, why did you use $\frac{1}{w}\log \frac{1}{1-w}$? I don't see how the $\frac{1}{w}$ enters the game here?

Comment: @DanielFischer, when $w=e^{-2\pi y}$, the $dy$ becomes a constant times $dw/w$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't make the substitution, I let $\int e^{-2\pi ky}\,dy$ stand.

Comment: @DanielFischer, ah yes, I guess I included an unnecessary substitition.

Comment: I see. I did compute the second integral via mathematica and it give me $\frac{1}{12}$, but I do not know how to use it properly. Thanks!

Comment: I finished the computation in my head. This is ingenious!